# How to sort data if for-each is absent

Tags: xslt

Consider the following input XML:

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Christians</artist>
    <year>2005</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <artist>Abba</artist>
    <year>2001</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

The example below presents the data sorted by artist using `<xsl:sort>`

```
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Year</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <xsl:sort select="artist" />
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to sort my data if the XSL does not contain an explicit `<xsl:for-each`, but the looping is taken care of by `<xsl:apply-templates`, as in the next example.
I've tried using `<xsl:sort` right under the line with `<xsl:template match` but that gives me the error `element sort is not allowed within that context`.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/cd" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/catalog/cd[year='1982']">
    Artist = <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
    <xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/catalog/cd[year!='1982']">
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xsl:sort` element can be a child of either `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates`.

Example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cd[year=1982]">
             <xsl:sort select="artist" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
    <artist>
        <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
    </artist>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
  <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
</output>
```